# Probability Functions of Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say we have some random variable $X$ with a known pdf, and another random variable $Y=X^2$. If we want to find the pdf of $Y$, a lot of textbooks proceed by looking at the cdf $P(Y\leq y)$ and not a pdf like $P(Y=y)$. Thus we end up looking at $P(X\leq\sqrt{y})$, and then when we differentiate the function to get the pdf instead, we also end up using the term $\frac{d}{dy}\sqrt{y}$ - if we just did the transformation with the pdf instead, we would just get $P(X=\sqrt{y})$ and I'm not seeing where we also need to differentate with respect to $\sqrt{y}$. What is the reason/difference for this? Thanks!

Comment: Since you have a continuous random variable, $P(Y=y)$ is just $0$. By definition the cumulative distribution function is a definite integral of the probability distribution function and so to obtain the pdf you should differentiate the cdf.

Comment: @daruma oh I see, this makes sense for the continuous case - in the discrete case though, we could just look at $P(Y=y)$?

Comment: Don't forget that $P(Y\le y)=P(-\sqrt y \le X \le \sqrt y)$ and the the derivative with respect to $y$ will involve $f(-\sqrt y)$ as well as $f(\sqrt y)$ and so on.

Comment: The transformation between PDF is just the chain rule. Set the CDF equal to the integral from the infimum of $X$ to some value $x$, then use change of variable for integrales and if you compare what is inside each integral, you'd ser the relationship $f_Y(y)=f_X(y)*(dx/dy)$. Also you could think of the transformation as preserving probabilities. Let $g:X\to Y$, then $P(x\in [a, b])=P(y\in [g(a),g(b)])$